# Why doesn't my lambda seem to do anything when called?

Tags: python, lambda, rgb

I have a lambda using sty that attempts to create colored text in a function I can just stick anywhere. However, when I run my code, the function fails to return anything (even None!) and I don't understand why.
A sample test:

```
from sty import fg, bg
colored = lambda entered_string, rgb: fg(rgb[0], rgb[1], rgb[2]) + bg(128, 128, 128) + entered_string + fg.rs

print(colored('hello world', (0, 255, 0)))
```

The expected (and desired) output would be 'hello world' printed out in green. However, as I said before, nothing prints, not even 'None'! It just goes straight to 'Process finished with exit code 0'.

Comment: what do the `fg` and `bg` functions do?

Comment: This won't have anything to do with lambdas. Is `fg.rs` supposed to be `rs.fg` though?

Comment: fg sets the text color, bg sets the background color, if you put .rs after either, it resets to the default.

Comment: @Carcigenicate no. I got a `NameError: name 'rs' is not defined1`

Comment: You need to import it along with `fg` and `bg`.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't be using lambda like this, `name = lambda : whatever`. That **defeats the entire purpose of lambda expressions** which is to provide anonymous functions. If you are going to name your function, then just use a regular function definition statement instead of a lambda expression. That's actually the official style recommendation according to PEP8

Comment: Actually, cannot reproduce. This code works for me. The most likely explanantion is your console doesn't support ANSII escape codes, which are likely what it's using behind the scenes.

Comment: Yeah, what does `result = colored('hello world', (0, 255, 0)); print(type(result)); print(repr(result))` give you?

Comment: `<class 'str'>` `'\x1b[38;2;0;255;0m\x1b[48;2;128;128;128mhello world\x1b[39m'`. So ya.

Comment: same here. `<class 'str'> ` `'\x1b[38;2;0;255;0m\x1b[48;2;256;256;256mhello world\x1b[39m\x1b[49m'`

Comment: @MrHiTech So your console likely doesn't support the coloring. Not all do. Try a different one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're running this code in the wrong kind of environment. In a jupyter notebook, it matches the description of your desired output:

[image]

Comment: interesting; it was working before, but then it just stopped randomly. I assumed I had messed something up and could not replicate what I'd had before